# Reading and deleting the object in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

**Scenario**

I have a scenario of Reading and deleting the object.I am using a CSV File for Reading the method,Request and test data.
I will be getting a token on retrieving a object based on search condition and need to use the same token in the next request for deleting the object.

**Following Steps were tried**

I tried to to store the token from the get request in a variable and referred the variable in delete request but the value is not getting reflected.
In debug sampler the value is getting reflected but not in the request.

**Test plan image**

[image]

**Screenshots for the request in CSV and response received**

[image]

Comment: It should work. is it the same thread group and thread? Can you show some details on Token variable?

Comment: not enough information, please post relevant parts of code / return data

Comment: I have updated the question with relevant screenshots and information

Answer (score 0):

It will not work this way, you need to use [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) in order to **evaluate** the variable coming from CSV file

So wrap your request "Path" into __eval() function like:

```
${__eval(/${ApiName}/${ApiVersion}/${ClientApiName}/${Request}/Token)}
```

And it should evaluate the value of `${Token}` variable from the CSV file.

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)